# How do I perform parallel asynchronous POST API calls in R?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, post, future

I have created an API endpoint on AWS Lambda which I invoke using a POST request  (with JSON data input) to get the result as a response (as a JSON data output).

Now I have 1 million data.tables that I need to process using the API. One API execution roughly takes 600ms and AWS Lambda allows upto 3000 requests per second. For faster execution I want to use all 64 cores in my system to generate 64 concurrent requests but I don't want these requests to wait till they get a response (the result) before they generate the next 64 requests and so on (Basically I want to hit the 3000 request threshold). For this I need to generate requests asynchronously with each request not waiting for it's response and once the response is generated to append it to a large list or data.table

I've looked into the **curl**, **Rcurl**, **future** and **doFuture** package documentations but couldn't find anything that solves this problem. Any help would by appreciated

I found a similar question on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194876/asynchronous-post-requests-r-using-rcurl) but the answer wasn't complete.

Example pseudo code to be run inside an asynchronous foreach (or similarly functioning function):

```
output = foreach(i = 1:n) %dopar%
{
  x = input[i]
  body = toJSON(x)
  url = "https://exampleURL.amazonaws.com/dev/LambdaTest"
  response = as.data.table(fromJSON(content(POST(url,
                                                 body = body,
                                                 content_type_json()))))
  return(response)
}
```

Here **data** is the data.table containing **n** subsets that need to be passed individually.

Comment: Have a look at this example https://github.com/jeroen/curl/blob/master/examples/crawler.R

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crul` package. It has two async interfaces, `Async` for many URLs that are all treated the same, and `AsyncVaried` to which you can construct HTTP requests in any configuration, then pass them to `AsyncVaried` to handle the async requests on those

```
library(crul)
```

Form the requests

```
req1 <- HttpRequest$new(
  url = "https://httpbin.org/post", 
  headers = list(`Content-Type` = "application/json")
)$post(body = jsonlite::toJSON(iris[1,]))
req2 <- HttpRequest$new(
  url = "https://httpbin.org/post", 
  headers = list(`Content-Type` = "application/json")
)$post(body = jsonlite::toJSON(iris[2,]))
```

Create an AsyncVaried object

```
out <- AsyncVaried$new(req1, req2)
```

Do requests

```
out$request()
```

Get status codes, headers, etc.

```
out$status_code()
```

Get json responses and parse to R lists

```
lapply(out$parse(), jsonlite::fromJSON)
```

Comment: How do I pass the POST request JSON and receive the response JSON using this package? Also I need to invoke 3000 API calls in a second which would require me to send 64 requests (because my system has 64 cores) at a time.

Comment: updated the answer. As to how you chunk your requests, we don't have any official support for doing things across cores - but perhaps you can do that with other R pkgs, then `crul` just handles the async requests per each core

Comment: I have to create close to 150,000 **crul** requests in a `list()` that I want to pass to `AsyncVaried$new()`. Now this takes ages if I'm using `lappy()`. But when I make the request list using `mclapply()` or `parLapply()`, `out$request()` throws me the following error: `Error in curl::handle_setopt(h, .list = w$options) : handle is dead`

Comment: Are you planning to include some sort of parallel processing feature in the crul package similar to what grequests has done for Python? I've looked everywhere and couldn't find any way to do this. There are two bottlenecks. One while creating the post requests and the other while sending them asynchronously. If a parameter which accepts a cluster object or the no. of cores in a system was introduced in both the `HttpRequest()` and `AsyncVaried()` functions it could tremendously improve performance

Comment: Would be better to take this to the repo now in an issue - let's discuss here  https://github.com/ropensci/crul/issues/47